# NHibernate, update read only collection outside of Session (changed an immutable collection instance)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, session, nhibernate

I am trying to test a simple object editing via `NHibernate` and I am getting some strange result.

I have this class mapping tag objects as a Tree :

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
    private IList<Tag> childTag = new List<Tag>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> ChildTag
    { get { return childTag.ToArray(); } }

    public virtual void Add(Tag child)
    { childTag .Add(child); }

    public virtual bool Remove(Tag child)
    { return childTag .Remove(child); }
}
```

with this map:

```
public TagMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("Kint_T01_IdTag")
        .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    HasMany(x => x.ChildTag)
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .Cascade.All()
            .Access.CamelCaseField().ReadOnly();
}
```

doing a simple test:

```
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uow.Start();
            uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            uow.End();

            // Act
            Tag.remove(Tag.Children.First());

            uow.Start();
            uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            uow.End();

            uow.Start();
            TagActual = uow.TagRepository.GetById(Tag.Id);

            //Assert
            TagActual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(Tag);
            uow.End();
        }
```

I get this error :

```
NHibernate.HibernateException : changed an immutable collection instance: [Gedi.Domain.Object.Entity.Tag.Children#21]
```

While I run the test in single session (without closing session between operation), all goes well and no exception is raised (except for the fact that `NHibernate` does not update the table as I would like as I have reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261562/nhibernate-and-tree-map-table-is-not-updated-after-removing-child-from-parent-c))

Need some guidance on this and what could be the steps to resolve this.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

this is the way that works

```
        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uow.Start();
            uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            Tag.Remove(Tag.Children.First());
            uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            uow.End();

            uow.Start();
            TagActual = uow.TagRepository.GetById(Tag.Id);
            TagActual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(Tag);
            uow.End();
        }
```

but i think that in business code i may have the necessity of work outside session, so i would like to make it run in any case.

i edit some method name because i do not expose session and session concept outside of Data Access layer given that session is specific of NHibernate

**EDIT 2:**

this too works fine:

```
using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uow.Start();
            uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            uow.End();

            // Act
            Tag.Description = "EDITED";

            uow.Start();
            uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
            uow.Commit();
            uow.End();

            uow.Start();
            TagActual = uow.TagRepository.GetById(Tag.Id);

            //Assert
            TagActual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(Tag);
            uow.End();
        }
```

only the collection give error outside session

Answer (score 0):

I see some options

- Use a single session and check if you have a way to execute a session `flush` to persist your changes to database.
- Use a single session but adding transaction, then commit it before `Act` to persist your changes.
- Use a merge to attach an element to a different session `session.Merge(Tag)`
- Get the element from database on every new session you open instead of using the same instance

Comment: thanks for answering. in my Uow, Start create a session and a transaction, commit is obvious and End close the session. about your ideas see my update

Comment: @gt.guybrush: instances belong to a session so you need to do something so use it on a different one. Normally your session scope is long enough to avoid having to deal with multi-session issues. If it's a web application, the session is normally per request so in very weird situations you have to deal with cross session issues. Did you test `session.Merge(Tag)` to attach an instance to a different session?

Comment: i do not expose session, so i cant use merge. at this point i can use the edit i posted. I was just hoping to be able to work out from a session without problems. what I thought was odd was that everything worked except the collection. P.S. while we're can you give me a hand to releted question i link above? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25261562/nhibernate-and-tree-map-table-is-not-updated-after-removing-child-from-parent-c)